# Double sums of positive numbers and enumerations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say I have a set of positive numbers indexed over two indices $\{a_{(m,n)}: m,n \in \mathbb{N}\},$ with $a_{(m,n)} > 0$ for all $m,n.$ I am interested in proving that for every enumeration over these indices (i.e. a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$), we have the following equality

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{f(i)} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{(m,n)}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Some ideas: I know that if there exists some $f$ such that Equation (1) holds, then it holds for any $f,$ since rearrangements of positive series do not change the value of the sum. Then we can pick some enumeration and prove Equation (1) holds for this case. I'm thinking we can prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{f(i)} = \sup_{M,N \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^N a_{(m,n)},$$
but nothing that I've tried has worked.

Comment: Isn't the sum on left just rearrangement of the one on right? And if we know rearrangement doesn't change sum then what could stop them from being equal?

Comment: There's no enumeration of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ whose sum takes the form on the right-hand side of (1). If you think about the matrix (a_(m,n)), the right-hand side of (1) entails enumerating $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ one row at a time. But there is no bijective function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow  \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ that does this (you never get to the second row). The typical construction of a bijective $f$ would scan across this matrix in a diagonal zig-zag pattern.